# Скрипт для для смены даты в сводной таблице Excel

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Как написать скрипт для обновление даты(берутся из ячеек `H2` `I2` `J2`  ) в сводной таблице в excel 2016 
С помощью записи макроса получил это

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица13").PivotFields( _
    "[Date Reporting].[Calendar YMD].[Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица13").PivotFields( _
    "[Date Reporting].[Calendar YMD].[Month Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица13").PivotFields( _
    "[Date Reporting].[Calendar YMD].[DT]").VisibleItemsList = Array("", "", _
    "[Date Reporting].[Calendar YMD].[DT].&[ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Статистика).Cells(2, 8).Value]", _
    "[Date Reporting].[Calendar YMD].[DT].&[2018-04-02T00:00:00]", _
    "[Date Reporting].[Calendar YMD].[DT].&[2018-04-09T00:00:00]")
```

Данные в ячейки формируются формулой `ТЕКСТ(СЕГОДНЯ()-2;"ГГГГ-ММ-ДДTчч:мм:сс")`

Comment: `& ТЕКСТ(A1;"ГГГГ-ММ-ДДTчч:мм:сс")` или `& ТЕКСТ(СЕГОДНЯ()-2;"ГГГГ-ММ-ДДTчч:мм:сс")`. Ну или в VBA-коде аналогично применить функцию `FORMAT()`.

Comment: @Akina ту же ошибку выдает (1004)

Comment: *ту же ошибку выдает* В исходном сообщении про ошибку ничего не было, так что слова "ту же" видеть странно. Вероятно, как-то не так делаете... замените, например, `"[Date Reporting].[Calendar YMD].[DT].&[2018-04-02T00:00:00]"` на `"[Date Reporting].[Calendar YMD].[DT].&[" & Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Статистика).Range("A1").Value;"ГГГГ-ММ-ДДTчч:мм:сс") & "]"`, есссно заменив A1 на нужный адрес ячейки.

Comment: @Akina сейчас ругается на ";" что после Value. А проблема может в том что я все это делаю в коде макроса(редактирование макроса)?

Answer (score 0):

нашел "[Date Reporting].[Calendar YMD].[DT].&[" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Статистика").Cells(2, 8.Value & "]", _ помогло